# Calling a Cloud Function from Android through Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

### Situation

I have created a Google Cloud Function through `functions.https.onRequest`, which is working nicely when I paste its URL in a browser and integrates well with my Firebase setup. This function is meant as somewhat of an API method exposed from the backend, which I'd like to invoke from clients. In this particular instance, the client is an Android app.

### Question

Is there any way I can perform the HTTP request for the Cloud Function by invoking it through Firebase? Or will I have to still perform a manual HTTP request?

Comment: what do you mean? Invoking the function using Firebase SDK?

Comment: For example, if I have an `https` function accessible at `https://<server>.cloudfunctions.net/newSession`, I'd expect to be able to call something like `FirebaseFunctions.getInstance().get("newSession")`, similarly to how other Firebase functionality is accessed.

Comment: What I can suggest is to file a feature request for this functionality, because AFAIK there's no available standalone SDK for Firebase Functions yet.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since version 12.0.0 you can call cloud function in more simple way

Add following line in your `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.2'
```

And use following code

```
FirebaseFunctions.getInstance() // Optional region: .getInstance("europe-west1")
    .getHttpsCallable("myCoolFunction")
    .call(optionalObject)
    .addOnFailureListener {
        Log.wtf("FF", it) 
    }
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        toast(it.data.toString())
    }
```

You can use it on main thread safely. Callbacks is triggered on main thread as well.

You can read more in official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: How to add header authorization with this?

Comment: @RahulSharma authorization info is added automatically by sdk

Comment: Can we pass arguments to this cloud function ?? Can we only call cloud functions or we can also create and add cloud functions from android code ??

Comment: @PradeepkumarReddy arguments are passed as map (see `optionalObject` in code snippet), just make sure they are encodable to JSON. Create and add functions from client? It's possible, but will require service account == HUGE security hole (dunno why on earth you would like to be able to do that)

Comment: Man, You save me some bucks. Thanks

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I didn't know, that I also had to provide the functions region client side!!!!!!

Answer (score 10):

*firebaser here*

Update: There **is** now a client-side SDK that allows you to call Cloud Functions directly from supported devices. See Dima's answer for a sample and the latest updates.

Original answer below...

---

@looptheloop88 is correct. There is no SDK for *calling* Google Cloud Functions from your Android app. I would definitely [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

But at the moment that means you should use the regular means of calling HTTP end points from Android:

- [Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)
- [Android: AsyncTask to make an HTTP GET Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399294/android-asynctask-to-make-an-http-get-request)
- [Http Get using Android HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654876/http-get-using-android-httpurlconnection)
- [Android's HTTP Triggers documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: Can we call Google Cloud Functions from an Android app today?

Comment: @TheGameChanger Yes. If you have a problem, I recommend you create a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you give me a link, please?

Comment: I don't have a problem. I just want to know how exactly are we supposed to call Google Cloud Functions from an Android app? I need a link, a name or a description?

Answer (score 6):

It isn't possible for now but as mentioned in the other answer, you can [trigger functions using an HTTP request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) from Android. If you do so, it's important that you protect your functions with an authentication mechanism. Here's a basic example:

```
'use strict';

var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log('helloWorld called');
  if (!request.headers.authorization) {
      console.error('No Firebase ID token was passed');
      response.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
      return;
  }
  admin.auth().verifyIdToken(request.headers.authorization).then(decodedIdToken => {
    console.log('ID Token correctly decoded', decodedIdToken);
    request.user = decodedIdToken;
    response.send(request.body.name +', Hello from Firebase!');
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
    response.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
  });
});
```

To get the token in Android you should use [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) and then add it to your request like this:

```
connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", token);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Yes it's possible :

1. #### Add this to **app/build.gradle** file :

   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.0'

---

2. #### Initialize the client SDK

   private FirebaseFunctions mFunctions;

   mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();

---

3. #### Call the function

   ```
   private Task<String> addMessage(String text) {

   Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
   data.put("text", text);
   data.put("push", true);

   return mFunctions
           .getHttpsCallable("addMessage")
           .call(data)
           .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
               @Override
               public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                   // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                   // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                   // propagated down.
                   String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                   return result;
               }
           });
      }
   ```

---

[Ref : Calling Firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)