# Cloud Functions for Firebase HTTP Request

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to send an HTTP Request from Android to a cloud function, post some values, then input these values into real time database.

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.testPost = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see three steps in here:

1. **Calling a Cloud Function from Android**.

   This is the same as calling any other HTTP URL from Android. See
   [Calling a Cloud Function from Android through Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872743/calling-a-cloud-function-from-android-through-firebase)
2. **Parsing parameters from the call in your Cloud Function**

   A HTTP triggered Cloud Function is really just an Express handler. So parsing the post works the same as for other Express handlers. The [Firebase documentation for HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request) has some examples and links to other documentation.
3. **Posting to the database from a Cloud Functions**

   All the samples in the [functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) include the Firebase Admin SDK. This SDK allows you to access many Firebase features, such as the database, from within your function. But there's also an [example in this repo](https://github.com/mimming/zero-to-app-universal-translator/blob/master/js/functions/index.js#L43).