# How to add firebase function to an Android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firebase function, I need to use my Firebase Function methods in my Android app. Can anyone please help me out on how to connect the Firebase function and use the methods in Android Studio

Note: I have added the Firebase Database, Auth and a few other dependencies to my Android project

Comment: Try reading official firebase documentation .

Comment: @RishabhMaurya I tried by didn't get any help

Comment: That really depends on the type of Cloud Function you have. If it's a HTTP triggered function, calling it as as simple as loading a URL from your Android app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44427085/cloud-functions-for-firebase-http-request/44428441#44428441

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank You, i'll check the above link