# I want to show images in GridView from ftpserver and i am getting FileNotFound Exception

Tags: android, gridview

I can access the same folder and file through FileZilla very easily.
Definitely I am doing something wrong, but what ?
My code is as below

```
    try{  
    Bitmap bitmap = null;  
    InputStream in;  
    String userpass = "username:password";  
    String url = "http://veedeesoft.com/httpdocs/RoyalFoods/Products/Large/1.png";  
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();  
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");  
    c.setDoInput(true);
    String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(android.util.Base64.encode(userpass.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));  
    c.addRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);  
    c.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");  
    c.connect();  
int status = c.getResponseCode();  
                if(status >= HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST){  
                    in = c.getErrorStream();  
                }else{  
                    in = c.getInputStream();  
                }

}catch(Exception e){  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: Check out your url. Its `404`.

Comment: Can you guide how the url should be to connect ftp server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
      try{  
            Bitmap bitmap = null;  
            InputStream in;    
              HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urls[0]).openConnection();  
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");  
            c.setDoInput(true);

            c.connect();  
            int status = c.getResponseCode();  
            if(status >= HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST){  
                in = c.getErrorStream();  
            }else{  
                in = c.getInputStream();  
            }

         }catch(Exception e){  
             e.printStackTrace();  
         }

         return null;
    }
 }
```

Use it like this:

```
new HttpGetTask().execute("http://veedeesoft.com/RoyalFoods/Products/Large/1.png");
```

Also make sure you have the Internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it's not working is because you need to run it in a background thread, I would prefer you use AsyncTask ([Android: AsyncTask to make an HTTP GET Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399294/android-asynctask-to-make-an-http-get-request))

Comment: Transferred code to Async Task but still getting int status = 404.

Comment: I think there is some problem in my url. String url = http://veedeesoft.com/httpdocs/RoyalFoods/Products/Large/1.png; Is this the right way of writing url while connecting ftp server ?

Comment: http://veedeesoft.com/RoyalFoods/Products/Large/1.png, this is working in the browser. I removed "httpdocs" because thats the site hosting folder (veedeesoft.com)

Comment: No, this is not working in the browser because it is secured by username and password. But works fine with Filezilla.

Comment: It does I get Amul butter image in the browser. The whole authorization code you using is not needed. As far as I know you are accessing a HTTP image URL, not an FTP.

Comment: Oh yes, it does. It means I have to remove httpdocs from my string url...

Comment: Yes and the basic authorization and change you Content Type to application/octet-stream

Comment: Removed basic Authorization also, but same 404. Definitely i am doing something wrong...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android. You don't even need this  c.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: Removed c.setRequestMethod("GET"); Removed Content-Type but still same 404